# Why this discord.js query to mongoose didn't work?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I try to submit data to mongoodb using discord.js command, Why this code didnt work ?

```
const subregis = "!reg ign: ";
client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content.includes(subregis)){
      const user = new User({
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        userID: msg.author.id,
        Nickname: msg.content.text.substr(9)
      });
      user.save().then(result => console.log(result)).catch(err => console.log(err));
      msg.reply("Data already submited")
  }
})
```

Comment: What is the behaviour you get when you run the code? Any errors or unexpected things happening?

Comment: @Caladan Nothing happen, no one error, and i see nothing on my database

Comment: Is the result being logged to the console or is the message reply in the last line working?

Comment: No, the message reply didnt work

Comment: There is no property called `message.content.text`. `message.content` by itself is the string which has the message content.

Comment: THANK YOU I CHANGE IT TO msg.content.substring(msg.content.indexOf(':') + 1) AND IT WORK FINE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Tried different methods to find you problem and I think I found the problem.
This is the code after I changed it:

```
// you could also do rather than .includes, you could do if (message.content === "!reg ign: ") rather than having to make it more complicated
// maybe change substr to substring although they both work also there is no message.content.text so I fixed that
// you could create a const text = args[0]; where it will fetch the users first text displayed example: "!reg ing hello" and I will have a username called hello
client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === "!reg ign: "){ 
      const user = new User({
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        userID: msg.author.id,
        Nickname: msg.content.substring(msg.content.indexOf(":" + 1) // so basically anything after the : will be the username
      });
      user.save().then(result => console.log(result)).catch(err => console.log(err));
      msg.reply("Data has been submitted successfully") 
  }
});
```

Comment: Btw it will didnt work if i didnt put .includes there,

Comment: ahh ok, thats why well happy i helped